# SSE version of modf

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sse, simd

I have the following working implementation of `modf` using SSE intrinsics, but it seems quite wasteful to be converting to `__m128i` and back in the process, when I need the result as a `__m128`.

```
__m128 integer = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(value));
__m128 fraction = _mm_sub_ps(value, integer);
```

Does there exist an instruction for truncation without type conversion, or some magic number hack?

Comment: Do you have access to SSE4.1 or XOP?

Comment: @Mysticial Unfortunately no, though what instruction would I use in SSE4.1?

Comment: `roundpd`. That gives you the integer part. Then subtract that from the original number to get the fractional part. You can control the rounding mode to get what you want.

Comment: @Mysticial Ah cool, I must have missed it. I can not use it, but I will accept it as an answer if you write it as one, for the sake of others.

Comment: k, gimme a sec to write it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With SSE4.1, you can use the [`roundps` and `roundpd`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-DAFA16CE-DB78-4FFD-9C1E-4AE0EA96CEA7.htm) instructions:

```
//  Single Precision
__m128 integer = _mm_round_ps(value,_MM_FROUND_TRUNC);
__m128 fraction = _mm_sub_ps(value,integer);

//  Double Precision
__m128d integer = _mm_round_pd(value,_MM_FROUND_TRUNC);
__m128d fraction = _mm_sub_pd(value,integer);
```

This will separate the integer and fractional parts while preserving the sign for both of them.

Likewise, for AVX:

```
//  Single Precision
__m256 integer = _mm256_round_ps(value,_MM_FROUND_TRUNC);
__m256 fraction = _mm256_sub_ps(value,integer);

//  Double Precision
__m256d integer = _mm256_round_pd(value,_MM_FROUND_TRUNC);
__m256d fraction = _mm256_sub_pd(value,integer);
```

---

If you also have the XOP instruction set, you can get the fractional part alone with only one instruction (via `_mm256_frcz_pd` and family).

But without SSE4.1, then there isn't really a better way to do it aside from converting, or doing the +/- magic number trick. (both of which will run into problems in the case of overflow)

Comment: Could you give some info regarding the magic number trick? My input set is very limited.

Comment: For double precision, `x = x + (3*2^51) - (3*2^51)` will round `x` to the nearest integer. But it only works if `-2^51 < x < 2^51` holds. The same trick works for single-precision with a different exponent. But that said, this rounds rather than truncates. It might be possible to make it truncate by means of adding/subtracting `0.5` in the right places.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a path worth exploring.

Comment: I've tried it, from my tests it is roughly the same speed as the original double conversion method.

Comment: Then that's probably the best you can do. In the case of double precision, it helps more since you don't have int64 <-> dp conversion instructions. But after all, the fact that roundp/d exists in the first place is because there probably wasn't a good way to do it before hand.